# css background transparency?

Tags: css, transparency, opacity, rgba

So I've been wasting a lot of time trying to do something simple. Using a custom css plugin I've been trying to set my body to be transparent to see the image in the background.

What I first tried using was opacity selector, but that set everything in the body as transparent. I'd like to have my images and text not be transparent. I've been googling this for many hours and each answer I see for other people is to use the rgba (number, number, number, opacity). I can see how this would work, but using this does not make the background transparent at all. I'm really at a loss for what to do, I feel like there is just something really simple I am missing.

Please inspect my code to see where I've gone wrong: [jaredbabinec.com][1]

Also here is my css:

```
    body {

 opacity: .9; 
}

.site-header {

rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);

}



.site-content {
  background-color: rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.9)
}
```

Comment: what's the problem here? The body is transparent. I can see the background image

Comment: @Anandhunadesh Body is transparent but I don't want the images and text to be. The only thing that's making anything transparent is opacity: but that just makes everything transparent in the body

Comment: got it..pls check my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the background color of the div with id="page"

for example

```
#page{
background-color: rgba(185, 178, 178, 0.71);
}
```

change the color as needed.  Hope this will fix ur problem

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.site-content {background: rgba(210,210,210,0.9)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`
.site-header {

rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);

}
`

rgba is not a property, it is a value you left out background:

Give the body the background image with background-size set to cover.

You want to create a site-wrapper div that is height and width 100%.
Make the background for that div transparent